# How to make a dll for windows 64b with a fortran function compiled with cygwin?

Tags: excel, vba, dll, cygwin, shared-libraries

I used to make fortran dlls in the past (on Windows 7) with g95. I have now a 64b Windows 10 with Excel 2016 (32 bits) and I try to redo the same thing.

I have installed cygwin (for 64b) with gfortran from the i686-w64-mingw32 suite.
I have this helloworld fortran function:

```
    $ more helloworld.f90
       function hello()
       integer hello
       hello=1
       return
       end
```

I build the dll by doing:

```
gfortran -fno-underscoring  -c helloworld.f90
gfortran -shared -o helloworld.dll  helloworld.o
```

(I have made sure the dll works when called from a fortran file
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61251244/build-and-link-a-fortran-dll-to-a-fortran-code-with-gfortran-in-cygwin).
Note it has been necessary to use 'gfortran' to compile and link to the dll, and it didn't work with 'i686-w64-mingw32-gfortran.exe')

Now, I want to use it in Excel, so I wrote this VBA code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Declare PtrSafe Function hello Lib "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Desktop\helloworld.dll" (M As Long) As Long

Function gohello(M As Long) As Long
gohello = hello(M)
End Function
```

When now I want to use it in the spreadsheet (with a simple formula like "=gohello(1)" ) I obtain #VALUE! .

I am pretty sure it is not a pb of location: (the spreadsheet and the lib are in the same directory) : VBA simply cannot "see" the dll.

Thanks, in case some one has already faced this...

Comment: Use Cygwin 32bit and the fortran cross compiler to build a NOT cygwin binary https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Fmingw64-i686-gcc-fortran%2Fmingw64-i686-gcc-fortran-9.2.0-2&grep=gfortran

Comment: @matzeri : Thank you for reply. I have installed Cygwin32 and I have checked that I have exactly the configuration described in the link you provide. Unfortunately I get:   $  gfortran -shared -o helloworld.dll helloworld.o  
gfortran: erreur fatale: « -fuse-linker-plugin », mais cyglto_plugin.dll introuvable
compilation terminée.

Comment: @matzeri : I have solved part of the pb. The version of gcc and gfortran were not at the same level. They now both are at 9.2.0 and I can link the program. Nervertheless, when I build a dll, Excel still cannot access to it...

Comment: you should use `i686-w64-mingw32-gfortran.exe` for a pure windows program

Comment: I have just done this:  $  i686-w64-mingw32-gfortran.exe -shared -o helloworld.dll helloworld.o  .Still,the dll is not read...