# Build and link a fortran dll to a fortran code with gfortran in cygwin

Tags: dll, linker, fortran, cygwin, mingw32

I built a fortran dll and I try now to use it in a fortran main. The problem is I cannot link correctly the main to the dll.

I am on WIndows10 and I use gfortran from cygwin (the 32 bit version of cygwin, gfortran comes from the suite i686-w64-mingw32).

Here is the dll:
$ more helloworld.f90

```
function hello()
integer hello
hello=1
return
end
```

I complile and generate the dll like this:

```
gfortran -fno-underscoring  -c helloworld.f90
gfortran -shared -o helloworld.dll  helloworld.o
```

Here is the main
$ more usehello.f90

```
program usehello
integer, external :: hello
integer :: i
i=1
write(*,*) hello(i)
stop
end
```

compilation is OK:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gfortran.exe -c  -fno-underscoring  usehello.f90
```

link fails:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gfortran.exe  usehello.o helloworld.dll -o usehello
error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran-5.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Yet, I do have this file:

```
$ ls -l  /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/libgfortran-5.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 UT013536+l-pg164999 UT013536+Aucun 2460672  4 mars  04:46 /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/libgfortran-5.dll
```

I have tried to add --static-libgfortran (I wasn't not convinced of using something 'static' for a dll but so...): 
It links apparently correctly but the executable fails:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gfortran.exe  usehello.o helloworld.dll -static-libgfortran -o usehello
$ ./usehello
usehello.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libquadmath-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Sounds like if an environnement variable was missing but I cannot find any post reporting on this kind of fail. Thanks in case some one can help...

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the idea to use the command i686-w64-mingw32-gfortran.exe is not good...if we simply use gfortran it works fine...